# How to read from Stream trait

Tags: rust

I have the following type:

```
pub type MessageStream = Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Result<rtsp_types::Message<Body>, ReadError>> + Send>>;
```

and a struct member:

```
stream: Option<MessageStream>,
```

That I call like this:

```
self.stream.as_mut().unwrap().poll_next();
```

but I get

```
116 |         let response = self.stream.as_mut().unwrap().poll_next();
    |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&mut Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<rtsp_types::Message<Body>, message_socket::ReadError>> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>`
```

On https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html it lists only `poll_next`, but `into_future()` worked for me for some reason.

It's nice to convert to a future but I also want to `poll_next`, I'm trying lots of things.

What is wrong?

Comment: look at [the latest doc](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#tymethod.poll_next). It requires a Pin of &mut Self (Pin<&mut Self>) for some reason so you can't just use a mutable reference to the pin.

Comment: @Deadbeef thanks, `let iterator = Pin::new(self.stream.as_mut().unwrap()).poll_next` now works but I don't have a context to pass. How should I poll this stream to receive items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are writing a `Future` or an *executor* you should probably not be calling `poll_next()`. You should instead use [`next()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.next) from the [`StreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html) trait in an `async` context.

```
use futures::StreamExt;

// ...

self.stream.as_mut().unwrap().next().await;
```